# Adobe Air, not able to open html content in new window

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flex3

I am not able to solve this issue despite trying very hard, hence posting it here.

As the title says, I have an Adobe air desktop app and when I click a button I want to display one html content from a remote server.

I have tried two approaches, namely HtmlLoader and StageWebView. These are opening a new Window, but not displaying the html content.

My sample html file -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Action script code -

```
var windowOptions:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
windowOptions.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.STANDARD;
windowOptions.type = NativeWindowType.NORMAL;
var newWindow:NativeWindow = new NativeWindow(windowOptions);
newWindow.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
newWindow.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
newWindow.activate();

var htmlLoader:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
htmlLoader.width = newWindow.stage.stageWidth;
htmlLoader.height  = newWindow.stage.stageHeight;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
htmlLoader.load(request);
newWindow.stage.addChild(htmlLoader);
```

But the htmlLoader is not displaying the content. Even I tried with asynchronous method -

```
htmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
```

but even then no content!

I tried with StageWebView, as documented [here](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html#includeExamplesSummary), but even then the same problem!

```
var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
webView.stage = this.stage;
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight );
webView.loadURL(url);
```

I went through all the examples as mentioned [here](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e74.html), don't know whether I should try any other alternative approach.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Just in case, does it work if you attach **HTMLLoader** or **StageWebView** instances to the main window?

Comment: As a quick test... Try using actual numbers instead of `.stageWidth` and `.stageHeight`. This is to make sure your app is not getting size `0` for page display size.

Comment: Hi @VC.One - thanks a lot. Setting the value of .stageWidth and .stageWidth to proper intergers made all the difference. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently built an AIR desktop app for MacOS and Windows and came across lots of issues with StageWebView. I ended up using a ANE.

[Tuarua Webview ANE](https://github.com/tuarua)

Regarding your code above:

- The url variable is not being set.
- Set width and height as hard coded **integers** to ensure width or height is not being set to `0`.
- Initially test with a trusted url like `www.google.com` to rule out issues with your own server.

Comment: Hi @crooksy88, thanks a ton! I hard coded the values of .stageWidth and .stageWidth to proper intergers and now the html content is being displayed. Thanks for your help!